# Save Spyder (Anaconda) profiler output

Tags: python, profiling, anaconda, spyder

Spyder, which is the IDE that comes with Anaconda python distribution, has an integrated code profiler, that can be easily used by simply pressing F10 within the IDE.

Is it possible to save it to file (maybe csv/txt), so to share it with other team members or simply review it later?

Otherwise, can you please point me to other code profiler tools that allow this?

EDIT: I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving Profiler data can be done if you are using Spyder **3.0** or higher. As you can see below, you only need to press the button called *Save data* to do it:

[image: Profiler screenshot]

*Note*: You can also load previous data and the Profiler will show diff times between your previous and current results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case I am using Python 2.7...any idea?

Comment: That's your Python version, not your Spyder version. Simply update Spyder to get this functionality, I think it couldn't be clearer than that ;-)

Comment: I got so focused on the bold 3.0 that I didn't read the word before...thanks a lot ;)